# How do you make a gameobject stay on top of another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm working on the full version for a [puzzle platformer I made,](https://gabrio-blu.itch.io/blockventures) where you switch between players, and in this case(or problem, idk), *carry other players that aren't being controlled.*

Basically I want the controlled player to be able to carry another player on it's head, and stil be able to jump as high. In the game jam version, I just set the rigidbody mass to zero and made the velocity the same as the cube under it. But now, if I do that, whenever I move, the player on top gets flung **extremely fast** and teleports around. Not exactly what I wanted.

I've tried making them both apply force for moving and jumping, but the top one jumped of the bottom one, and then they met in the air and the top one jumped again. I also tried using a fixed joint, but the movement was way too fast and broken, and they stuck together too well. I tried applying more force, but the top cube just jumped really high. I just can't win.

On top of that, whenever the top cube falls on the bottom cube in the air, the top one almost bodyslams the bottom one into the ground - they fall *really quickly*.

What I want is for the top cube to sit nicely on the bottom cube ***WITHOUT GOING HIGHER THAN THE BOTTOM CUBE***, just sitting on it, without making the jump lower, but to also easily be removed by a block pushing it off, and the bottom player jump going under it.

*EDIT*: Tried parenting the cube did not work, instead I got wierd glitches.

*EDIT 2*: I tried FixedJoint2D with a slightly different setup, and sometimes it works, but other times it breaks for no reason and the movement is wierd. Like... You're not supposed to jump that high.
Code:

```
        //amControlled is true if this is the player that is being controlled.
        if (!amControlled)
        {
            //rayHitGroundLeft and rayHitGroundRight are raycasts off the left side of the bottom side and the right side of the bottom respectively.
            if ((rayHitGroundLeft && rayHitGroundLeft.collider.CompareTag("Player")) || (rayHitGroundRight && rayHitGroundRight.collider.CompareTag("Player")))
            {
                if (!gameObject.TryGetComponent(out FixedJoint2D joint))
                {
                    joint = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint2D>();
                }

                joint.connectedBody = rayHitGroundLeft.rigidbody;
                // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-breakForce.html
                // this allows the other collisions simply breaking this connection
                joint.breakForce = 100f;
                // Shall these two objects still be able to collide with each other while they are attached?
                // And shall other objects attached to the same body collide with each other?
                joint.enableCollision = true;

                rb.mass = 0f;
            }
            else
            {
                if (gameObject.TryGetComponent(out FixedJoint2D joint))
                {
                    Destroy(joint);
                }
                rb.mass = 1f;
            }
        }
```

[image: jumping way too high]

Comment: I would just disable all physics for the cube you are holding. Position it relatively to the other one, then child it. Now as it is an object positioned relatively to your moving one, it will not interact physically with anything and will just sit where you want it. If you still want the other cube to physically collide with other objects, change the layer it is on and in the physics settings make it so the first cube and second cube on the new layer do not physically collide with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it fixed! It took a while - well actually 11 days. Basically I have it restting it's velocity while it's on the player (with `rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * -50f, rb.velocity.y * -50f));`. I also add more force depending on how many players are on top of the player (by multiplying the force of the jump with one more than the players on top), and I made it wait a frame after landing before jumping. That stops the jumps from being lower when jumping onto and immediately off of a taller platform. Basically I'm now going to copy over the relevant code.

```
isGrounded = false;

        float length = 0.017f;
        float extraDistance = 0.004f;

        RaycastHit2D rayHitGroundLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x - boxCollider.bounds.extents.x + extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y - boxCollider.bounds.extents.y - extraDistance), Vector2.down, length, groundMask);
        Debug.DrawRay(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x - boxCollider.bounds.extents.x + extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y - boxCollider.bounds.extents.y - extraDistance), Vector2.down * length, color);

        RaycastHit2D rayHitGroundRight = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x + boxCollider.bounds.extents.x - extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y - boxCollider.bounds.extents.y - extraDistance), Vector2.down, length, groundMask);
        Debug.DrawRay(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x + boxCollider.bounds.extents.x - extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y - boxCollider.bounds.extents.y - extraDistance), Vector2.down * length, color);

        RaycastHit2D rayHitCeilingLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x - boxCollider.bounds.extents.x + extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y + boxCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraDistance), Vector2.up, length, groundMask);
        Debug.DrawRay(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x - boxCollider.bounds.extents.x + extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y + boxCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraDistance), Vector2.up * length, color);

        RaycastHit2D rayHitCeilingRight = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x + boxCollider.bounds.extents.x - extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y + boxCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraDistance), Vector2.up, length, groundMask);
        Debug.DrawRay(new Vector2(boxCollider.bounds.center.x + boxCollider.bounds.extents.x - extraDistance, boxCollider.bounds.center.y + boxCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraDistance), Vector2.up * length, color);


        //amControlled is true if this is the player that is being controlled.
        if (!amControlled)
        {
            //rayHitGroundLeft and rayHitGroundRight are raycasts off the left side of the bottom side and the right side of the bottom respectively.
            if ((rayHitGroundLeft && rayHitGroundLeft.collider.CompareTag("Player")) || (rayHitGroundRight && rayHitGroundRight.collider.CompareTag("Player")))
            {
                if (rayHitGroundLeft && rayHitGroundLeft.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
                {
                    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * -50f, rb.velocity.y * -50f));
                    //rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
                    //rb.AddForce(rayHitGroundLeft.rigidbody.velocity * 50f);
                }
                if (rayHitGroundRight && rayHitGroundRight.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
                {
                    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * -50f, rb.velocity.y * -50f));
                    //rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
                    //rb.AddForce(rayHitGroundRight.rigidbody.velocity * 50f);
                }

                //rb.mass = 0f;

                //rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!((rayHitDownLeft && rayHitDownLeft.collider.CompareTag("Player")) || (rayHitDownRight && rayHitDownRight.collider.CompareTag("Player")) || (rayHitUpLeft && rayHitUpLeft.collider.CompareTag("Player")) || (rayHitUpRight && rayHitUpRight.collider.CompareTag("Player"))))
                {
                    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * -50f, 0));
                }
                //rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * -50f, 0));
            }
        }

        if ((rayHitCeilingLeft && rayHitCeilingLeft.collider.CompareTag("Player")) || (rayHitCeilingRight && rayHitCeilingRight.collider.CompareTag("Player")))
        {
            playersAboveMe = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            playersAboveMe = 0;
        }

        if (amControlled)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                horizontal -= 1f;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                horizontal += 1f;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && isGrounded && wasGrounded)
            {
                isJumping = true;
                jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
                vertical = 10.4f;
            }
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                isJumping = false;
            }
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && isJumping)
            {
                if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
                {
                    vertical += 0.7f;
                    jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    isJumping = false;
                }
            }

            if (isGrounded && !wasGrounded)
            {

            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
            {
                isJumping = false;
                isGrounded = false;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                vertical -= 0.3f;
            }
        }

        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
        if (!(rb.velocity.x > 3f && movement.x > 0) && !(rb.velocity.x < -3f && movement.x < 0))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(movement.x * 20f, 0f));
        }
        if (!(rb.velocity.y > 5f && movement.y > 0))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, movement.y * 20f * (playersAboveMe + 1)));
        }
        if (rb.velocity.y > 5.5f)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y * -10f));
        }

        if (movement.x == 0 && amControlled)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * -50f, 0));
        }

        if (movement.x > 0)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
        }
        else if (movement.x < 0)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        wasGrounded = isGrounded;

        vertical = 0f;
        horizontal = 0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

First disable all that can move your top object, like rigidbody (make it isKinematic).
Then you can parent the top object to the bottom object (or maybe to an empty or bone on it's head) and thats it! When you parent an object to another, the parent will move the child.
For parent in code use "topObject.transform.SetParent(bottomObject.transform)"
And for un parent use "topObject.transform.SetParent(null)"

Comment: Trying it now, if it's that simple I will feel stupid for not thining about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html).

> Fixed Joints restricts an object’s movement to be dependent upon another object. This is somewhat similar to Parenting but is implemented through physics rather than Transform hierarchy. The best scenarios for using them are when you have objects that you want to easily break apart from each other, or connect two object’s movement without parenting.

You can easily attach this on runtime via

```
if(!yourObject.TryGetComponent<FixedJoint>(out var joint))
{
    joint = yourObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
}

joint.connectedBody = theBottomObject;
// See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-breakForce.html
// this allows the other collisions simply breaking this connection
joint.breakForce = FORCE_REQUIRED_TO_BREAK_APART;
// Shall these two objects still be able to collide with each other while they are attached?
// And shall other objects attached to the same body collide with each other?
joint.enableCollision = false;
```

And if you want to detach yourself it is as simple as setting

```
joint.enabled = false;
```

or

```
Destroy(joint);
```

Comment: Going to try it with break force of like, 2, and see if it works.

Comment: It is partially working, but whenever I move it's really fast.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need turn Top cube to a Kinematic by using scripts, then you need a reference of Bottom cube to get Rigidbody.position of it, let the TopCube.Rigidbody.position = BottomCube.rigidbody.position + offset ,with offset = new vector 3(0, TopCube's height/2 +0.01,0)(+0.01 to they do not overlap each other) .when you stop carry just return Top Cube to Dynamic.

Comment: But what about the top cube being pushed off?